# JSON returned, but Kendo Grid does not display data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a grid hierarchy as shown here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/hierarchy.html.

My basic structure is I have a main grid initialized from an html table that fires detailInit, and produces a child grid. The child grid reads from a controller method, which returns JSON. I have verified that the controller method is returning the correct, valid JSON, but the child grid only shows the column titles, without any data in the table's rows. The only exception I am getting is a javascript exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**Controller method:**

```
        public JsonResult GetDBA(string DBAName, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(repository.DBAs
            .Where(m => m.DBAName == DBAName)
            .ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

**Example JSON returned:**

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "DBAId": 25,
            "DBAName": "adam's hotdog store",
            "LegalEntity": "adam",
            "BusinessPhone": "1234567890",
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "EmailAddress": "test@email.com",
            "Address": null,
            "EIN": null,
            "DBAs": null,
            "Products": [],
            "ProductsList": null,
            "SelectedProductIds": null
        }
    ],
    "Total": 1,
    "AggregateResults": null,
    "Errors": null
}
```

**Table, which forms the DataSource for the main grid:**

```
    <table id ="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="DBAName">
                DBA
            </th>
            // ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (AppStatus.Domain.Entities.Contract contract in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>@contract.DBA.DBAName</td>
                //...
            </tr>

        }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Initialize the Kendo Grid from the table defined above:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Aging: {type: "number"}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 8
                },
                detailInit: detailInit,
                pageable: true,
                resizable: true
            });
```

**Bind the grid to the onDataBound function:**

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
}
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBound", onDataBound);
```

**detailInit:**

```
function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Admin/GetDBA",
                    data: {"DBAName": e.data.DBAName}

                }

            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "LegalEntity" },
            { field: "BusinessPhone" },
            { field: "AlternatePhone" }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: In which view you are getting this error? Which line? You can check that in browser dev tools F12. Most likely cause is JQuery is not loaded before any other JS library.

Comment: @SBirthare, thanks for the response. The error is in kendo.all.min.js line 11, and it is thrown when I expand the master row to show the detail row. The call before the call to kendo.all.min.js is jquery-1.9.1.js line 818. Not quite sure I understand. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Which Kendo version you are using? Kendo has dependency on particular JQuery. You might need to install latest or compatible version of JQuery as per Kendo version. See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

Comment: Make sure JQuery is loaded in the page before Kendo and only once. Just those silly things that cause such issue.

Comment: JQuery is indeed loaded before Kendo and only once (there is only one script reference to jquery, so it's only loaded once, right?) I am using the kendo mvc extension version Q2 2013, kendo.all.min.js v2013.2.918, and jquery-1.9.1.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can get the above exception to go away by defining schema: { model: { fields: {<fields go here>}}} inside the dataSource in detailInit. I get 'Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined' if I instead change the schema to data: "data" as I have seen suggested. But my data is still not displayed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work, but I still have no idea why my previous function was not displaying data. Here is my final, working function:

```
    function detailInit(e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/GetDBA",
        data: { DBAName: e.data.DBAName }
    })
      .done(function (data) {
          $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
              dataSource: data.Data,
              columns: [
                  { field: "LegalEntity" },
                  { field: "BusinessPhone" },
                  { field: "AlternatePhone" }
              ]
          });
      });


}
```

Comment: Thanks in 2021!!.. This is still better than ridiculously simplistic telerik examples in their demos.. and yes, just by seeing your code it clicked to me that our previous solution did not worked because using telerik transport layer , it was not waiting for ajax request to complete and so the data model was not getting updated.